# Android position crashes app

Tags: android, xml

This is the XML that I have:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivRockPic"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/image_border" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:id="@+id/llAns1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAns1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Ans1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAns1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:id="@+id/llAns2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAns2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Ans2"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAns2"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:id="@+id/llAns3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAns3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Ans3"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAns3"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:id="@+id/llAns4"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAns4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Ans4"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAns4"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAnswer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Next" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Just posted one button. And this repeats. This set up works perfectly fine. Tested, initialized in the bean, it is working. But here is the issue, when I move the ImageView above the TextView, it throws me an error on the initiation line of the view where I fetch the ImageView id. But when I move it back, it works fine. Any ideas?

Error:

The two method inside are just initializations of strings:

```
res = getResources();
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivRockPic);
        tvAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswer);
        initializeRussian();
        initAnswerList();
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        iViews[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAns1);//dies
        iViews[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAns2);
        iViews[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAns3);
        iViews[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAns4);
        lLayouts[0] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAns1);
        lLayouts[1] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAns2);
        lLayouts[2] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAns3);
        lLayouts[3] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAns4);
        tViews[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAns1);
        tViews[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAns2);
        tViews[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAns3);
        tViews[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAns4);

06-29 23:57:09.838: E/AndroidRuntime(5236): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rock.school.rzn.rockquiz/rock.school.rzn.rockquiz.GameScreen}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at rock.school.rzn.rockquiz.GameScreen.initialize(GameScreen.java:171)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at rock.school.rzn.rockquiz.GameScreen.onCreate(GameScreen.java:47)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the onCreate() code at least and the logs of the crash :)

Comment: Posted the error source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seemed to be a weird bug. I tried repositioning it, rebuilding, adding new components and in the end, I just remade the file with a different name and it worked. I think it was a problem with the file or Eclipse path or something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the logs, the error is that you are trying to cast the `ImageView` to `TextView` or viceversa, the issue is in the method `initialize()` from the `GameScreen` class and at line *171*..

**See here:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
06-29 23:57:09.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5236):     at rock.school.rzn.rockquiz.GameScreen.initialize(GameScreen.java:171)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCastException` means that you are trying to cast something to an incompatible type. In your case, the line

```
iViews[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAns1);
```

retrieves something with the id `R.id.ivAns1` and tries to cast it to an `ImageView`. Judging by the exception message, the view with this id is actually a `TextView`, that's why your cast fails.

Though the view with the id `ivAns1` in your XML is an `ImageView`, I would carefully examine the rest of the file to make sure that no other element has the same id. Also try recreating your R file.

Comment: I said that I just copy paste it. No changes at all.

Comment: @Alexey I don't see the whole XML, and the problem apparently lies there. Or you use some other layout than this one.